# How to control the task execute order in Android studio's build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 4.1 and Gradle 6.7.1

(Note that the "mergeReleaseAssets" is not my custom task, it is part of the system tasks, and I don't know where to find the definition of "mergeReleaseAssets")

**I want to set the task "mergeReleaseAssets" to be executed after "myTask" as below:**

```
...
> Task :app:myTask
...
(no matter how many tasks in the middle should be ok)
...
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
...
```

**The task definition in the build.gradle:**

```
...
task myTask {
    doLast {
        println String.format("put something in the assets")
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { t -> t.finalizedBy myTask }
...
```

When building the project by clicking Menubar -> "Build" -> "Rebuild Project", the task execute order is not always the same, it seems the tasks are executed in parallel.

**The build output for the first time:**

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleRelease] in project /home/testproject

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:myTask
> Task :app:compileReleaseSources
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease
> Task :app:packageRelease
> Task :app:assembleRelease

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 0s
32 actionable tasks: 30 executed, 2 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available
```

**The build output for the second time:**

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleRelease] in project /home/testproject

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :app:myTask
> Task :app:compileReleaseSources
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease
> Task :app:packageRelease
> Task :app:assembleRelease

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 54s
32 actionable tasks: 30 executed, 2 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available
```

**As you can see, at the first time, the order is "myTask" -> ... -> "mergeReleaseAssets".**
**But the second time, it changed to "mergeReleaseAssets" -> ... -> "myTask".**

And then, I try to set the task dependency in the build.gradle:

```
project.getTasks().getByName("mergeReleaseAssets").dependsOn(myTask)
//This also not work
//project.getTasks().getByName(":app:mergeReleaseAssets").dependsOn(myTask)
```

**But Android studio shows error:**

```
Task with name "mergeReleaseAssets" not found in project ':app'

//Or this error if using ":app:mergeReleaseAssets":
Task with name ":app:mergeReleaseAssets" not found in project ':app'
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: you should try to wrap the creation of the dependency in a `afterEvaluate` closure; indeed, if the `mergeReleaseAssets` is a task dynamically created by one plugin, it might not be available during configuration of your project. try :  `project.afterEvaluate{ project.getTasks().getByName("mergeReleaseAssets").dependsOn(myTask) }`

Comment: Hi, @M.Ricciuti, I have tried your solution, it works. Thanks. Please write your comment as an answer, and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `mergeReleaseAssets` task is dynamically created, so you cannot reference it directly in your `build.gradle` script.

One solution is to use the `Project.afterEvaluate` lifecycle hook as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:project_evaluation)

```
project.afterEvaluate{ 
    // at this stage, task 'mergeReleaseAssets' has been declare, you can reference it to perform additional configuration
    project.getTasks().getByName("mergeReleaseAssets").dependsOn(myTask) 
}
```